# Offset and lag for kafka consumer (created via new consumer api) are set to unknown

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer, kafka-consumer-api

I am often seeing issue in which kafka consumer gets current offset and lag set to unknown
Earlier consumer was having offset and lag

```
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER  
G.AB_KAFF, T.AB_KAFF, 0, 3, 6, 3, consumer-2
G.AB_KAFF, T.AB_KAFF, 1, 8, 11, 3, consumer-2
```

When I subscribed this consumer again after few days its offset and lag is set to unknown

```
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER  
G.AB_KAFF, T.AB_KAFF, 0, unknown, 7, unknown, consumer-2
G.AB_KAFF, T.AB_KAFF, 1, unknown, 11, unknown, consumer-2
```

Is kafka removing previous offsets for that consumer since I am unsubscribing whole consumer group from topic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is kafka removing previous offsets for that consumer since I am
>   unsubscribing whole consumer group from topic ?

yes, you are right.
`offsets.retention.minutes=1440 (24 hours)` default is 24 hours.
Log retention window in minutes for offsets topic